# How to create a single executable file with dependencies included?

Tags: c++, windows, executable, sfml, game-development

I coded a little game in C++ using SFML. Then I wondered if there was any way to create a single executable with all the images, sounds and dependencies inside. That way, I could send to my friends only a single .exe file ready to be played instead of sending a .zip file with the executable AND the dependencies inside.

I have searched about this on the internet but seems that people only shows how to create an installer, which is not what I want.

The file structure looks like this:

```
./game-build
├── main.exe
├── yoshi.ogg
└── yoshi.png
```

And the goal is to make a standalone executable with yoshi.ogg and yoshi.png
somehow "included" inside the .exe file.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White gcc